# Share WPF window between few applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have a .NET console application named, for example "App №1", which can handle user interface in WPF UserControl. And i can run multiple instances of this application with different parameters from console. Now i want to create WPF application "App №2", which will run multiple instances of "App №1" using System.Proccess class. The question is: Is there any way to point for each instance of "App №1" to a UserControl in "App №2" Window so all instances of "App №1" share the same window. Or is there better way to share single window between WPF applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use named pipes for communication between your apps.